# How to fetch schema from graphQL API endpoint

Tags: graphql, codegen, graphql-codegen

I need to fetch a schema from graphQL API endpoint.
So the result must be a string like:

```
  type User {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
  }

  type Home {
    user: User!
    address: String
    country: String!
  }

  type Query {
    MyUsers: User!
  }
```

Is it possible to do by using codegen?

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the GraphQL server you are using, Some GraphQL servers provide a GraphQL Explorer. The GraphQL Explorer is a page where you can manually input GraphQL queries into the page such as Graphiql

Other way is to try out [graphql-cli](https://github.com/Urigo/graphql-cli) you can do with the below command,

```
get-graphql-schema ENDPOINT_URL -j > schema.json
```